# Fedora, vagrant and libvirt

Tags: vagrant, libvirt

In my continuing attempts to get vagrant up (* [No kernel sources available for 4.4.4-301.fc23.x86_64](https://superuser.com/questions/1056971/no-kernel-sources-available-for-4-4-4-301-fc23-x86-64?noredirect=1#comment1483516_1056971)) I have been trying to use the libvirt provider because libvirt is faster and does not require installing virtualbox. It is my preferred provider for fedora-based systems.

I am trying to debug a client's wordpress installation and am using the box here: http://vccw.cc/

Of course it is a virtualbox. After mutating it (via the vagrant-mutate plugin) to libvirt, I encounter a strange problem.

```
vagrant up --provider=libvirt
Bringing machine 'vccw.dev' up with 'libvirt' provider...
==> vccw.dev: Creating image (snapshot of base box volume).
==> vccw.dev: Creating domain with the following settings...
==> vccw.dev:  -- Name:              vccw-2190_vccwdev
==> vccw.dev:  -- Domain type:       kvm
==> vccw.dev:  -- Cpus:              1
==> vccw.dev:  -- Memory:            512M
==> vccw.dev:  -- Management MAC:    
==> vccw.dev:  -- Loader:            
==> vccw.dev:  -- Base box:          miya0001/vccw
==> vccw.dev:  -- Storage pool:      default
==> vccw.dev:  -- Image:             /var/lib/libvirt/images/vccw-2190_vccwdev.img (40G)
==> vccw.dev:  -- Volume Cache:      default
==> vccw.dev:  -- Kernel:            
==> vccw.dev:  -- Initrd:            
==> vccw.dev:  -- Graphics Type:     vnc
==> vccw.dev:  -- Graphics Port:     5900
==> vccw.dev:  -- Graphics IP:       127.0.0.1
==> vccw.dev:  -- Graphics Password: Not defined
==> vccw.dev:  -- Video Type:        cirrus
==> vccw.dev:  -- Video VRAM:        9216
==> vccw.dev:  -- Keymap:            en-us
==> vccw.dev:  -- INPUT:             type=mouse, bus=ps2
==> vccw.dev:  -- Command line : 
==> vccw.dev: Auto-generating node name for Chef...
==> vccw.dev: Creating shared folders metadata...
==> vccw.dev: Starting domain.
```

... And this is where it hangs.

Sometimes it gets one step further:

```
 ==> vccw.dev: Waiting for domain to get an IP address...
```

Assuming that it could be a problem with dnsmasq and DHCP, I tried changing the Vagrantfile in a number of ways.

First, I decided to manually specify the hostname:

```
 config.vm.hostname = "vccw.dev"
```

Then I decided to manually specify the IP address:

```
 #config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"
 config.vm.network :private_network,
        :ip => "192.168.33.10"
```

However, nothing seems to prevent the vagrant from hanging on "Waiting for domain to get an IP address."